# How do I properly test with error objects?

Tags: go

So let's assume I have a function I would like to test. This function would look something like this:

```golang
func coolFunction(input int) (error, int) {
  if input == 1 {
    err := error.New("This is an error")
    number := 400
  } else {
    err := nil
    number := 200
  }

  return err, number
}
```

If I would like to test this function, with positive and negative cases, I would have to write a test function like this:

```golang
func TestCoolFunction(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        input int
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name         string
        args         args
        wantError    error
        wantInt      int
    }{
        {"No error", 
            args{
                0,
            }, 
            nil,
            200,     
        },
    }
}
```

So this works quite well. But how would I test the negative case, where the error object is not `nil`?

My goal is to know if `error != nil`, so the test shows PASS as result, while using the above structs. Any ideas?

Comment: First thing I notice: Every function that returns an error should return the error as the _last_ argument. So you should change to `func coolFunction(input int) (int, error) {`.

Comment: @Abhijit-K: I would like to run [Table Driven Tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests). How would I do this in this case?

Comment: why `if err == nil` then `t.Error("Failed")` does not work for you?

Comment: You can use `reflect.DeepEqual` or some other such tool that compares an interface value's underlying data. https://play.golang.org/p/YHM62DJWfAY

Comment: @wenga, I understand you are doing that table driven. Which is a fancy name, the approach is still same. Check the answer please if that is what you are looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, you want to check proper error return on certain conditions.

Here is:

```
func coolFunction(input int) (int, error) {
    var err error
    var number int
    if input == 1 {
        err = errors.New("This is an error")
        number = 400
    } else {
        err = nil
        number = 200
    }

    return number, err
}
```

Then in test file, you need to have an understanding or protocol on the fact that you expect error (rightfully). Like a flag below `expectError bool`, which will be true for your case.

You can also have field for specific error type and check if returned type is exactly that.

```
func TestCoolFunction(t *testing.T) {

    var testTable = []struct {
        desc        string
        in          int
        expectError bool
        out         int
    }{
        {"Should_fail", 1, true, 0},
        {"Should_pass", 100, false, 200},
    }

    for _, tt := range testTable {

        t.Run(tt.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
            out, err := coolFunction(tt.in)
            if tt.expectError {
                if err == nil {
                    t.Error("Failed")
                }
            } else {
                if out != tt.out {
                    t.Errorf("got %d, want %d", out, tt.out)
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Adding the specific error check using `DeepEqual` suggested by @mkopriva

```
func TestCoolFunction(t *testing.T) {

    var testTable = []struct {
        desc        string
        in          int
        expectError error
        out         int
    }{
        {"Should_fail", 1, errors.New("This is an error"), 0},
        {"Should_pass", 100, nil, 200},
    }

    for _, tt := range testTable {

        t.Run(tt.desc, func(t *testing.T) {
            out, err := coolFunction(tt.in)
            if tt.expectError != nil {
                if !reflect.DeepEqual(err, tt.expectError) {
                    t.Error("Failed")
                }
            } else {
                if out != tt.out {
                    t.Errorf("got %d, want %d", out, tt.out)
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Also `DeepEqual` is for demonstration, you should use actually some different approach to check errors which is faster. This depends on how errors are designed in your application. You can use sentinel errors or type/interface check. Or const based enum field in custom error type.